# Swap values in 2 textboxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm making a simple calculator with 4 inputs a,b,c & d and need to have the ability to swap the values of c & d. For example textbox c has a value of 45 & textbox d has a value of 75. A button is clicked which swaps the vales so c=75 & d=45

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Full Javascript Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fd86r/)

Javascript :

```
function swapValues(){
var tmp = document.getElementById("c").value;
document.getElementById("c").value = document.getElementById("d").value;
document.getElementById("d").value = tmp;

}
```

and HTML :

```
<input type="text"  id="a" value="1st" />
<input type="text"  id="b" value="2nd" />
<input type="text"  id="c" value="3rd" />
<input type="text"  id="d" value="4th" />
<input type="button"  id="go" onclick="swapValues()" value="Swap">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery, and your inputs have the right ids, this should do:

```
var t = $('#c').val();
$('#c').val($('#d').val());
$('#d').val(t);
```

It's quite trivial, though...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your HTML looks something like this:

```
<input id="input-c">
<input id="input-d">
```

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (I'd recommend it), you might do it like this:

```
var temp = $("#input-c").val();
$("#input-c").val($("#input-d").val());
$("#input-d").val(temp);
```

You could optimize this a little bit if you wanted, but it adds a couple of lines:

```
var $inputC = $("#input-c");
var $inputD = $("#input-d");
var temp = $inputC.val();
$inputC.val($inputD.val());
$inputD.val(temp);
```

If you're not using jQuery, you might do something like this:

```
var inputC = document.getElementById("input-c");
var inputD = document.getElementById("input-d");
var temp = inputC.value;
inputC.value = inputD.value;
inputD.value = temp;
```

In general, this is a common programming pattern when swapping the value of two variables. You have to make a temporary variable before you can do the swapping, otherwise one variable will clobber the other.

Comment: There's no reason to involve jQuery in this, so the last part of the answer is the way to go.

Comment: @JaimeTorres, if the OP is already using jQuery in his page, using it makes sense. Of course, loading jQuery just for those 3 lines would be overkill.

Comment: @jcaron I completely agree, but as this sounds like homework, I doubt this is the case.

Comment: and no `jQuery` tags placed.

Comment: @JaimeTorres my first instinct was to comment on the question "what code have you written yet?" or "what is actually the problem?", but then I got soft... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The concept could be like this using Vanilla javascript...

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="od" class="firstInput" />
<input type="text" placeholder="do" class="secondInput" />
<span class="inputExchange">
    <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt float-right"></i>
</span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let firstInput = document.querySelector(".firstInput");
let secondInput = document.querySelector(".secondInput");
let temp;
let inputExchange = document.querySelector(".inputExchange");
inputExchange.addEventListener("click", exchangeValue);

function exchangeValue() {
  temp = firstInput.value;
  firstInput.value = secondInput.value;
  secondInput.value = temp;
}
```